# Define $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $ \ f(x)=x^2,$ if $x<0,$ $x^2+2x ,$ if $x \geq 0.$

Tags: derivatives

Define $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $ \ f(x)=\begin{cases} x^2, & \text{if } x<0, \\ x^2+2x, & \text{if } x \geq 0. \end{cases}$

Then which of the following statements are correct ?

(i) $ \ f''(x)=2 \ $ for all $ \ x \in \mathbb{R} \ $

(ii) $ f''(0) \ $ does not exist

(iii) $ f'(x) \ $ exists for each $ \ x \neq 0 \ $

(iv) $ \ f'(0) \ $ does not exist

**Answer:**

At first try to check whether $ \ f'(x) \ $ exists or not at $ \ x=0 \ $ .

Then,

$$
R \ f'(0)= \lim_{h \to 0^{+}} \frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0^{+}} \frac{h^2+2h}{h}=2
$$

$$
L \ f'(0)= \lim_{h \to 0^{-} } \frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0^{+}} \frac{h^2}{h}=0
$$

Thus $ L \ f'(0) \neq R \ f'(0) \ $

Thus $ \ f \ $  is not differentiable at $ \ x=0 \ $

This means $ \ f'(0) \ $ does not exists.

Thus option $(iv)$ is correct .

Also option $(iii)$ is also correct.

Therefore  $(iii)$ and $(iv)$ are correct.

**I need confirmation of my work.**

**Is there any help?**

Comment: I changed the title to be one line, please try to avoid making more than one line title.

Comment: it seems allright.

Comment: what about (ii) ? How is that supposed to exist, when $f'$ is not defined in 0?

Comment: Option $(i)$ is wrong and $(ii)$ is right. $f''(0)$ cannot exist unless $f'(0)$ exists. In fact $f''(x)$ exists for every value of $x$ except $x=0.$ Your argument showing that $(iv)$ is right is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument showing that $(iv)$ is right is valid.

That $(iii)$ is right is shown by ordinary differentiation formulas, and can also be shown by finding limits as you did in the argument that shows that $(iv)$ is right.

$f''(0)$ cannot exist because $f'(0)$ does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

(i) $ \ f''(x)=2 \ $ for all $ \ x \in \mathbb{R} \ $

- false, see (ii)

(ii) $ f''(0) \ $ does not exist

- true, see (iv)

(iii) $ f'(x) \ $ exists for each $ \ x \neq 0 \ $

- true

(iv) $ \ f'(0) \ $ does not exist

- true